# How to enable Normal Scrolling on MacBookPro 10.8.3?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

Small or incremental scrolling on my MBP OSX 10.8.3 using an external mouse is extremely slow to a crawl. How do I configure my mouse to a Normal Scroll mode where every scroll is the same and creates fast scrolls in the window?

Comment: What mouse are you using?

Comment: Logitech Corded Mouse M500

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing the scroll speed in System Preferences > Mouse > Scrolling Speed:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I've already visited this option. yet every incremental scroll only scrolls the page by pixels.. Only large scrolls are normal.

Comment: Okay. Try the [Logitech Control Center](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/support/3129) (under Downloads). Then once it is installed, go to System Prefs > Logitech Control Center, select your mouse, then go to the General preferences and see if changing the scroll setting there fixes that.